# How to identify "Don't prompt for a password from other notes-based programs" is enabled using java

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

In all the example programs and tutorials, people are asking to set "Don't prompt for a password from other notes-based programs" before accessing mail database using Java.
If this is not checked, then the program prompts for password, but hangs after that. (different issue)

```
private void connectToMailDB() throws NotesException {
     Session session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();
     DbDirectory dbDir = session.getDbDirectory(null);
     Database db = dbDir.openMailDatabase();
     System.out.println("db Title : " + db.getTitle());
     System.out.println("Document Count : " + db.getAllDocuments().getCount());
}
```

The other method of creating session without getting hanged is to get credentials from the user and send that as a parameter using the below syntax.

```
NotesFactory.createSession(host, user, pwd);
```

What I want to achieve is that if the user enabled the security option " Don't prompt for a password...", then my program must start executing using the first block of code without prompting for credentials otherwise the program must ask the credentials from the user.

How can I get to know that the security option is enabled or not before proceeding.

It will be very much helpful if I could find some hint on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I checked in the notes.ini file by diffing a version captured before turning on that flag and a version captured after turning it on. I thought that setting would be in there, but it actually does not appear to be.

Comment: Yes, that setting will not be stored in notes.ini file. That setting is password protected, hence it might not be available in ini file. There must be some API which tells whether the option is checked or not without knowing the password. The intuition behind this is that, the notes (java) is able to verify internally without using the password. So there must be some way, but I'm unable to find it. Any hints will be of great help.